# Forcing equal width columns in an array environment with a custom command

Tags: arrays

I've defined a custom command `tractorQ` that takes four arguments and typesets them in a matrix-like notation using the `array` environment:

```
\newcommand{\tractorQ}[4]{
    \def\arraystretch{1.2}
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{#4} \\
            {#2} & | & {#3} \\
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{#1}
        \end{array}
    \right)
}
```

The input

```
\tractorQ{A}{BCDEFG}{H}{I}
```

produces the output

[image: LaTeX output]

but I'd like to center the pipe horizontally, that is, force the first and third columns of the `array` environment to have the same width. I know that I can achieve this for any instance of this notation either manually or using the `array` package and defining a custom column environment that uses a custom width. This requires setting the custom width separately for each instance of this notation, however, as the arguments of `\tractorQ` vary widely in width across instances. Is there a way to write a command that achieves this automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution with the `eqparbox` package. It requires the name of the box in columns 1 and 3 as an optional argument (`W` by default):

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\tractorQ}[5][W]{
\def\arraystretch{1.2}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{#5} \\
          \eqmakebox[#1]{$ #3 $} & | & \eqmakebox[#1]{$ #4 $} \\
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{#2}
    \end{pmatrix}
}

\begin{document}

\[ \tractorQ{A}{BCDEFG}{H}{I} \]

\[ \tractorQ[X]{A}{BCD}{H}{I} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is quite a nice solution, thank you! (+1)

Comment: This code also has the (to me) undesirable consequence that *all* the widths of the middle row cells, i.e., across all instances of \tractorQ in the document share a common width. So, if I add to the above code \tractorQ{J}{K}{L}{M}, the K and L cells are as wide as the BCDEFG cell in the existing instance. Is there a way to avoid this? I tried adding a fifth argument to tractorQ and replacing the relevant line with

\eqmakebox[#5]{$ #2 $} & | & \eqmakebox[#5]{$ #3 $} \\

so that in each instance of tractorQ I could use a dummy argument unique to that instance, but this generates an error.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve this issue? I looked through the package documentation, but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Actually, I've found that using a counter resolves this issue.

Comment: I couldn't fit a description of my solution in a comment, so I've written it up a separate answer (referencing this one). Thanks again!

Comment: Here is a solution: the name of the `\eqmakebox` is an optional argument of the `\tractorQ` command. If you have only one such command in your document, use the default (`W`).

Comment: @Travis: Yours is another nice solution (+1).

Answer (score 4):

The `\fixTABwidth{T}` macro of the `tabstackengine` package forces **all** columns to be equal width, if that works for you.  EDITED to place rows 1 and 3 in zero-width boxes, so as to avoid them influencing column width.

In this MWE, the intercolumn gap is set to 0ex and the interrow baselineskip is set to 14pt.

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{0ex}
\setstackgap{L}{14pt}
\newcommand\tractorQ[4]{\fixTABwidth{T}\parenMatrixstack{%
  &\makebox[0pt]{#1}&\\#2&|&#3\\&\makebox[0pt]{$#4$}&}
}
\begin{document}
\[\tractorQ{A}{BCDEFG}{H}{I}\]
\[\tractorQ{A}{BCD}{H}{IJKLM}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. This doesn't quite fit my needs, as $A$ and $I$ are in some instances rather wide, and in those instances it leaves good deal of awkward space on either side of the pipe.

Comment: @Travis Give me a second...I have an idea.

Comment: @Travis Please see if revision is any better for your needs.

Comment: Yes, this suits my needs nicely, thank you! (And +1 earlier, b.t.w.)

Answer (score 2):

A different approach based on the `w` column type provided by `array` and the `calc` package.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc,array}

\newcommand{\tractorQ}[4]{%
  \left(
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{array}{
    @{}
    >{$}w{c}{\maxof{\widthof{$#2$}}{\widthof{$#3$}}}<{$}
    |
    >{$}w{c}{\maxof{\widthof{$#2$}}{\widthof{$#3$}}}<{$}
    @{}
  }
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{#4} \\
  #2 & #3 \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{#1} \\
  \end{array}\right)
}

\begin{document}

\[
\tractorQ{A}{BCDEFG}{H}{I}
\qquad
\tractorQ{A}{B}{H}{I}
\qquad
\tractorQ{A}{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}XYZ\\W\end{array}}{H}{I}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also do that with `nicematrix`. It's easy to program but you will need two compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NewDocumentCommand {\tractorQ} { m m m m }
  {
    \begin{pNiceArray}{C|C}[columns-width=auto]
    \multicolumn{2}{C}{#4} \\
    #2 & #3 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{C}{#1} \\
    \end{pNiceArray}
  }

\begin{document}

\[
\tractorQ{A}{BCDEFG}{H}{I}
\qquad
\tractorQ{A}{B}{H}{I}
\qquad
\tractorQ{A}{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}XYZ\\W\end{array}}{H}{I}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the previous code]

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just to record a modification of the code in Bernard's helpful answer that produces behavior that I desired but which the original code does not entail. Replacing the `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` code there with

```
\begin{document}

    \[ \tractorQ{A}{BCDEFG}{H}{I} , \tractorQ{J}{K}{L}{M} \]

\end{document}
```

so that more than one instance of `tractorQ` is called, produces the output

[image]

In particular, the argument `W`, which functions as a label that tells the compiler which cells to equalize in width, is applied to every instance of `tractorQ` in the document. The result is that the cells containing the arguments *K* and *L* are wider than necessary.

One can modify this behavior by introducing a dedicated counter, using it as the argument of `\eqmakebox` in both instances, and incrementing it every time `tractorQ` is called:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcounter{tractorQcounter}

\newcommand{\tractorQ}[4]{
    \def\arraystretch{1.2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{#4} \\
        \eqmakebox[\thetractorQcounter]{$#2$} & | & \eqmakebox[\thetractorQcounter]{$ #3 $} \\
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{#1}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \stepcounter{tractorQcounter}
}

\begin{document}

\[ \tractorQ{A}{BCDEFG}{H}{I} , \tractorQ{J}{K}{L}{M} \]

\end{document}
```

This produces the output

[image]